# Issue with a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I don't know what happen with the dropdown menu, when I move the mouse I can't touch the dropdown :( I try with a line, modifing the padding and It makes me move all the line.. is all about the code below.. just si what you can do for me and thanks a lot

```js
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cssmenu').prepend('<div id="indicatorContainer"><div id="pIndicator"><div id="cIndicator"></div></div></div>');
    var activeElement = $('#cssmenu>ul>li:first');

    $('#cssmenu>ul>li').each(function () {
      if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        activeElement = $(this);
      }
    });


    var posLeft = activeElement.position().left;
    var elementWidth = activeElement.width();
    posLeft = posLeft + elementWidth / 2 - 6;
    if (activeElement.hasClass('has-sub')) {
      posLeft -= 6;
    }

    $('#cssmenu #pIndicator').css('left', posLeft);
    var element, leftPos, indicator = $('#cssmenu pIndicator');

    $("#cssmenu>ul>li").hover(function () {
        element = $(this);
        var w = element.width();
        if ($(this).hasClass('has-sub')) {
          leftPos = element.position().left + w / 2 - 12;
        }
        else {
          leftPos = element.position().left + w / 2 - 6;
        }

        $('#cssmenu #pIndicator').css('left', leftPos);
      }
      , function () {
        $('#cssmenu #pIndicator').css('left', posLeft);
      });

    $('#cssmenu>ul').prepend('<li id="menu-button"><a>Menu</a></li>');
    $("#menu-button").click(function () {
      if ($(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
      }
      else {
        $(this).parent().addClass('open');
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#cssmenu {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}

#cssmenu > ul {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 500;
}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}

#cssmenu.align-center ul {
  text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
   text-align: left;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#cssmenu > ul > #menu-button {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  color: #7a8189;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 32px;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu li.has-sub::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub::after {
  right: 18px;
  top: 6px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #7a8189;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover::after {
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
}

#indicatorContainer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

#pIndicator {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #2b2f3a;
  z-index: -2;
  -webkit-transition: left .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: left .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: left .25s ease;
  -o-transition: left .25s ease;
  transition: left .25s ease;
}

#cIndicator {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #2b2f3a;
  top: -12px;
  right: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}

#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: 70px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: 37px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li {
  position: relative;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  top: 44px;
  opacity: 1;
}

#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 170px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 170px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  width: 130px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #9ea2a5;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .35s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .35s ease;
  -o-transition: all .35s ease;
  transition: all .35s ease;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li a {
  text-align: right;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #8c9195;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > ul::after {
  content: '';
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  left: 30px;
}

#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > ul::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 30px;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub::after {
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #9ea2a5;
  right: 10px;
  top: 12px;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease, right 0.2s ease;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub::after {
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #9ea2a5;
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover::after {
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
  right: -5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub:hover::after {
  border-right-color: #ffffff;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  left: -5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header></header>
    <body>
        <div class="subheader">
            <div class="user_inside">
                <p>Welcome Giocconda</p>
                <div id="cssmenu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><img src="images/profile_icn.png"></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
                                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
#cssmenu ul ul{
  position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 50px;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
-moz-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
-ms-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
-o-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
z-index: 1000;
  }
```

Change left position in css